# How to develop for Sharepoint 2010 in VisualStudio when your sharepoint server isn't on your local machine

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, timer-jobs

I am trying to program a timer job for sharepoint 2010. It's for my job at school and the sharepoint servers are located somewhere on campus where I don't have access to them.

I am new to visual studio, and when I try to create an empty sharepoint project, It tells me that I need to have sharepoint server installed on my machine in order to work with sharepoint.

I am just wanting to program a timer job for sharepoint in VS 2010, How do I do that without having sharepoint server on my machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have SharePoint installed for you to develop for it. No getting around that. You could just write pure CAML and use a standard C# assembly project for the DLLs, and use something like WSPBuilder to compile it into a deployable WSP file, though you would be unable to test your development as you went along, and it would take you a horrendously long time to do so, too.

You can install SharePoint onto Windows 7 for development purposes ([Here's how.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx)) It's also highly (infact, imperatively) important that you have a test farm, separate from your development system AND the live system to perform integration testing of your solution before you deploy to live.

Comment: Good to know, thanks a ton for the advice. That points me in the right direction

Comment: I'm not trying to duplicate here, I got pulled away in the middle of posting, and I didn't get the nifty alert that someone had answered.

Comment: Heh, no worries, you posted some more links there so it still counts :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the server DLL's to your machine and register them. They are located here on the server:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI

Since you are working with the Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration you need the base Microsoft.SharePoint.dll

Even if you don't have a development / test server you can spin one up in a VM for testing rather than turning your production server into your test server.  You dont have to develop inside the VM's (althought this gives you the easy F5 deploy/debug via visual studio), you can just ship your solution into the VM, and do a test activation there.

Multiple Options for personal env:

[Download already configured VHD from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27417)

[Install directly on Windows 7](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/a88cad83-f595-4487-940e-f678ce47eb5f)

[Create a personal VM environment](http://geekswithblogs.net/manesh/archive/2010/05/28/building-the-ultimate-sharepoint-2010-development-environment.aspx)

[My favorite, easiest, and quickest route is to use CloudShare](http://www.cloudshare.com/Products/CloudShare-ProPlus/solution-showcase.aspx)